# Inserting data into sqlite database and retrieving and it is getting lost when after application restart

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my `ProfileOneFragment` I am updating data in `onTextChanged` method, but when I restart and retrieve the data to display in `TextView` it displays inital values at the time of creation.

This is my DBHelper class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "edentitydb", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile (" +
                "profileid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY," +
                "fname TEXT," +
                "lname TEXT," +
                "alias TEXT NULL," +
                "designation TEXT NULL," +
                "organization TEXT NULL," +
                "primary_number TEXT," +
                "secondary_number TEXT," +
                "email TEXT," +
                "fax TEXT NULL," +
                "office_address NULL," +
                "home_address NULL" +
                ")");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO profile values" +
                "(1,'fname','lname',null,null,null,'primary_number',null,'email',null,null,null)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO profile values" +
                "(2,'fname','lname',null,null,null,'primary_number',null,'email',null,null,null)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS profile");
        //onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertFname(String fn,int profile)
    {
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET fname='"+fn+"' WHERE profileid="+profile,null);
    }

    public String getFname(int profile)
    {
        String query = " SELECT fname FROM profile WHERE profileid =" + profile;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            String fn = c.getString(0);
            c.close();
            return fn;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    public void insertLname(String ln,int profile)
    {
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET lname='"+ln+"' WHERE profileid="+profile,null);
    }
    public String getLname(int profile)
    {
        String query = " SELECT lname FROM profile WHERE profileid =" + profile;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            String ln = c.getString(0);
            c.close();
            return ln;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    public void insertAlias(String al,int profile)
    {
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET alias='"+al+"' WHERE profileid="+profile,null);
    }
    public String getAlias(int profile)
    {
        String query = " SELECT alias FROM profile WHERE profileid =" + profile;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            String al = c.getString(0);
            c.close();
            return al;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    public void updateFName(String name,int profile){
        //db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET fname='" + name + "' WHERE profileid=1" , null);
    }
    public void updateLName(String name,int profile){
        //db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET lname='"+name+"' WHERE profileid=?",new String[]{profile+""});
    }
    public void updateAlias(String alias,int profile){
        //db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET alias='"+alias+"' WHERE profileid=?",new String[]{profile+""});
    }
    public void updateDesignation(String designation,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET designation='"+designation+"' WHERE profileid="+profile,null);
    }
    public void updateOrganization(String organization,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET organization='" + organization + "' WHERE profileid=" + profile, null);
    }
    public void updatePrimaryNumber(String number,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET primary_number='" + number + "' WHERE profileid=" + profile, null);
    }
    public void updateScondaryNumber(String number,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET secondary_number='" + number + "' WHERE profileid=" + profile, null);
    }
    public void updateEmail(String email,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET email='" + email + "' WHERE profileid=" + profile, null);
    }
    public void updateFax(String fax,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET fax='" + fax + "' WHERE profileid=" + profile, null);
    }
    public void updateOfficeAddress(String address,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET office_address='" + address + "' WHERE profileid=" + profile, null);
    }
    public void updateHomeAddress(String address,int profile){
        db.rawQuery("UPDATE profile SET home_address='" + address + "' WHERE profileid=" + profile, null);
    }

    public String getProfileDetails(int profile,String field){
        String str="";
        Cursor cursor=db.query("profile",new String[]{field},"profileid="+profile,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            str=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(field));
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

And this is my Fragment to handle

```
public class ProfileOneFragment extends Fragment {

    public ProfileOneFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    DBHelper db;
    Context context;
    Spinner spinner_salutation;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    EditText fone_fname,fone_lname,fone_alias;
    ImageView fone_dp;
    ProgressBar fone_progressBar;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_one, container, false);
        context=getContext();
        db=new DBHelper(context);
        fone_progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.fone_progressBar);
        spinner_salutation=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_salutation);
        adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,R.array.salutations,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_salutation.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner_salutation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(context, parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        fone_dp=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fone_dp);
        fone_dp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        fone_fname=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fone_fname);
        fone_lname=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fone_lname);
        fone_alias=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fone_alias);

        String temp = db.getFname(1);
        fone_fname.setText(temp);

        String temp1 = db.getLname(1);
        fone_lname.setText(temp1);

        String temp2 = db.getAlias(1);
        fone_alias.setText(temp2);

        fone_fname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {




            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                String fn = fone_fname.toString();
                db.insertFname(fn,1);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                db.updateFName(s.toString(),1);
            }
        });
        fone_lname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                String ln = fone_lname.toString();
                db.insertLname(ln,1);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                db.updateLName(s.toString(), 1);
            }
        });
        fone_alias.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                String al = fone_alias.toString();
                db.insertAlias(al,1);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                db.updateAlias(s.toString(), 1);
            }
        });




        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: You've posted quite a lot of code here, and I suspect most of it is irrelevant to the problem. Have you tried to create a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as described in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? That is likely to help people give you more useful answers, and might well lead you to finding the answer yourself.

Comment: bur the code i have added is needed as a whole to be understood by the other person

Comment: Did you read the links I posted? Try creating a completely new project, with just a TextView, and the ability to insert and retrieve a single value. If that works, build it up and add in more of the functionality from your full application, until it stops working. Then start removing functionality until you're left with the smallest possible example that demonstrates your problem. Post that.